# Given $ ||\vec{u}|| = 2$, $||\vec{v}|| = 3$, and $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = -1$, find $(\vec{u} + \vec{v}) \cdot (2 \vec{u} - \vec{v})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Given $ ||\vec{u}|| = 2$, $||\vec{v}|| = 3$, and $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = -1$, find $(\vec{u} + \vec{v}) \cdot (2 \vec{u} - \vec{v})$.

Do I need to find what $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ actually are to answer this question or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Expanding we get $$2\vec{u}^2+2\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}-\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}-\vec{v}^2=4-2-9=4-11=-7$$

Comment: Why is it 4 - 2 - 9 = -7 instead of 2(4) + 2(-1) - (-1) - 9 = -2?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You just have to use these facts:

- $\vec u.\vec u=4$:
- $\vec v.\vec v=9$;
- $\vec u.\vec v=-1$.